# Why is my cat so mean to me when I leave for long periods of time?

Tags: cats, behavior

I am away at college for most of the year.

At first, whenever I came back, my cat seemed to be standoffish towards me and wanted nothing to do with me. Even she would sometimes growl or hiss at me. But after sometime she used to usually come around me.

Lately, for the last 2 times I’ve come home from college, she has not even come towards me after sometime. And today when I was walking through my house, she hissed and growled at me.

Does anyone know why this could be happening and what I can do about it?

Comment: how old is your cat?  And does she act like that towards strangers?

Answer (score 5):

Very often when this happens, it is because you have picked up different smells when you have been away,and cats are very dependent on their sense of smell to recognize their owner and other people.

So this behavior of your cat is because you smell wrong after being away. So the cat needs some time to understand it really is you.

Different cats have different ways to recognize their owner. Some cats depend on smell, others on look (if I put on thick winter clothes my cat no longer recognizes me and gets scared), some cats recognize you by sound and comes running when they hear you.

(My cat is an outdoor cat and she comes running when she hears me coming home in my car, so she reacts to the sound of my car but not to other cars. Also she comes when I call for her but she does not react if other people call for her.)